# using join in vb.net but it doesn't read information form access

Tags: vb.net

It's running but it deosn't read any data from the access(blank grid view), what's wrong please help me

```
Private Sub rrrrr(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles r1.Click, MyBase.Click, Button9.Click, Button8.Click, Button7.Click, Button6.Click, Button5.Click, Button4.Click, Button35.Click, Button34.Click, Button33.Click, Button32.Click, Button31.Click, Button30.Click, Button3.Click, Button29.Click, Button28.Click, Button27.Click, Button26.Click, Button25.Click, Button24.Click, Button23.Click, Button22.Click, Button21.Click, Button20.Click, Button2.Click, Button19.Click, Button18.Click, Button17.Click, Button16.Click, Button15.Click, Button14.Click, Button13.Click, Button12.Click, Button11.Click, Button10.Click, Button1.Click
    Dim b As Button = sender
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("select Customer.Name, Customer.Accompanion, Customer.Room_number, Rooms.Status from Customer inner join Rooms on (Customer.joint=Rooms.Status) where Room_number = '" & b.Text & "' ", con)
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    Form2.Show()

    If IsDBNull(DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value) And IsDBNull(DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(2).Value) Then
        Form2.Label1.Text = "--------"
        Form2.Label2.Text = "--------"
        Form2.Label3.Text = "--------"
    Else
        Form2.Label1.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value
        Form2.Label2.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(2).Value

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: SQL Injection risks here. Have you tried running the sql directly against the Access DB to see what it returns?

Comment: Use DB parameters.  Makes this sort of thing 100% easier to debug.  Ensure that b.Text value is exactly what you're expecting.  What is the data type of Room_Number in the db?

Comment: Are you sure that the relationship between the two tables in on Customer.joint=Rooms.Status?  I'd suggest breaking at da.SelectCommand = cmd, check value of cmd.CommandText and then run that command directly against the DB.  If that's OK, break after the fill and check what's in DT in case it is retrieving the data but your issue is displaying it.